# CGPointMake Accuracy

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have created a scene where I would like to have the character image move throughout the circle that I have created.

[image: a busy cat]

the character is an image view and the box containing the circle is an image view.

as of right now I have the image moving but it is throughout the entire scene. How would I limit the movement to just within the circle?

here is the code that I have so far:

`.h`

```
@interface FinalProjectViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIImageView *romo;
CGPoint pos;
NSTimer *romoMove;
}

-(void)romoMoving;
```

`.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

romoMove = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.09 target:self     
selector:@selector(romoMoving) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
pos = CGPointMake(5.0, 4.0); 
}

-(void)romoMoving
{
romo.center = CGPointMake(romo.center.x+pos.x, romo.center.y+pos.y);
    if (romo.center.x>170||romo.center.x<0) {
        pos.x = -pos.x;
    }
    if (romo.center.y>180||romo.center.y<0) {
        pos.y = -pos.y;
    }
}
```

I was thinking the best way to go about it was to find the points of the circle that I would like the character to hit then set those as the points as it should move to. I am not sure if that would be the best way to do this, nor was I very sure on how to accomplish this.

Comment: One easy approximation is to consider the distance between the center of the character image and the center of the circle, calculate the distance between them (e.g. using `hypot()`), and see if this is less than the radius of the circle (less the approximate radius of the character).

Comment: @Rob Thank you, I appreciate the suggestion. I will research how to do that.